# How to Count Cells Containing Specific Text and put the sum in different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I am working on some work allotted by the department, where I am stuck at some basic things.
I have 5 Google sheets in one file (say Sheet1, ... Sheet5). And in the second column every sheet I have entries from the list - "Book, Journal, Book Chapter". Now, I want to count number of entries as "Book" in all the sheets and put their sum in the last sheet (Sheet6).

I used the formula =COUNTIF(B2:B52,"Book") but unable to proceed further. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use COUNTIF to count the number of "Book" entries in the second column of each sheet. Enter the following formula in the last sheet:

```
=COUNTIF({Sheet1!B2:B52,Sheet2!B2:B52,Sheet3!B2:B52,Sheet4!B2:B52,Sheet5!B2:B52},"Book")
```

Comment: If the name of sheet1 is Mr. X and that of sheet 2 is Ms. Y, so do I have to write these exact names of the sheets?

Comment: Yes, replace 'Sheet1' with 'Mr. X' and 'Sheet2' with 'Mr. Y'.